# Rails associations - User and Events

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, associations

i've looked for a good answer but really couldn't seem to find one so i've had to post this question.

Im using Rails 4.0.1 and a bit of a beginner, i'm trying to implement 2 models, a user and an event.

I want users signed up to my website the capability to join **many events**, and therefore the events will have **many users** signed up to them.

Do I have to use **has_many** for both? I've tried it but it still doesn't recognise them when I add an event to a user using the rails console. I've created 2 migrations and 2 models.

The models i'm using are below

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :events
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :events
end
```

The migrations are:

```
class AddUserIdToEvents < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :events, :user_id, :integer
    add_index :events, :user_id
  end
end

class AddEventIdToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :event_id, :integer
    add_index :users, :event_id
  end
end
```

I can't seem to figure out how to set up the correct associations and cant figure it out. What do I have to do to allow users to sign up to many events and for events to have many users signed up to them? Thanks guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you need to set a many to many relationship between User and Event.
Go for has_and_belongs_to_many association in this case.

Model definition should be as follows:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :events
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users      ## users and not events
end
```

In many to many relationship, a join table is created which stores the primary keys of the main tables(users and events in your case).

So, destroy the two migrations that you created for adding foreign keys.
If you have already run the migrations then perform

```
rake db:rollback VERSION=versionnumber
```

Where replace versionnumber with the versionnumber prefixed on your migration file.
For eg: If your migration filename is 20140314190622_create_projects.rb then command should be

```
rake db:rollback VERSION=20140314190622
```

Do this for both the migrations AddUserIdToEvents and AddEventIdToEvents.

After this generate a migration for the join table users_events as

```
rails g migration CreateJoinTableUserEvent user event
```

This will create a migration for user_events( user_id, event_id ).

Run the migration using `rake db: migrate`

Read about **[Has and Belongs To Many Association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association)** in Rails Guides.
Also refer to **[Rails Migrations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#creating-a-migration)**.